# Visiting Canada from Italy with a trip to Mexico

Tags: canada, italy, mexico

Note that this is likely a novice question. A couple is visiting Canada from Italy, presumably on a single-entry Visa obtained upon arrival in Canada. In between their arrival and final departure from Canada, they have a return trip booked to Mexico from Calgary.

Given that the departure from Calgary would count as exiting Canada, I have two questions.

1. Would there be a complication returning from Mexico to Canada on Italian passports? I'm assuming it would just be another entry into Canada.
2. For the departure, would it be an issue if the original entry point was Vancouver but the exit is from Calgary?

Comment: Note that [Italian citizens do not need a visa to visit Canada](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/visit/visas.asp#exemptions).

Comment: Ah yes, probably not a 'visa' per se, but entry.

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out by Nate Eldredge, [Italian passport holders are exempt from obtaining a visa when visiting Canada](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/visit/visas.asp#exemptions). Going back via Canada when returning from Mexico is thus fine, it just counts as a separate entry. It does not matter whether the entry / exit points are different either.